# How to cache an API response and vary by Posted value as opposed to GET param

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple API and I'm posting in a ManufacturersRequest.
I'm aware of how to  VaryByQueryKeys but I see no examples of how to vary by something in the  'ManufacturersRequest' eg. ManufacturersRequest.Category.

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 600, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryBy???? =?????)]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Manufacturer>> Manufacturers([FromBody] ManufacturersRequest manufacturersRequest)



 public class ManufacturersRequest
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string manu_filter { get; set; }
    public int imagesize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user964787, did you read the official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conditions-for-caching)? It says the request method must be GET or HEAD.

Comment: Yes so  assume I go VaryByHeader. Is it just:

VaryByHeader=manufacturersRequest